# how to apply multiple format to a number in d3 json

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get something like

**12,345.6**

so d3 has format function if I use

`d3.format(".1f")`  I would get 12345.6

but if I use

`d3.format("0,000")`  I would get 12,345.600000000000

Comment: `d3.format("0,000")` works for me. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/0nw7jn16/).

Comment: @mdml if you do something like  console.log(d3.format("0,000")(1234000005/600000))  I doesn't give me the 1 decimal and comma ..

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I got it figured

```
d3.format(",.1f")
```

Just incase someone need it.